# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'cascade'

Tags: django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Python and the Django framework and have run into a problem that i can't find much information on, I'm currently following the django tutorial on:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

I keep running into this error -

> question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.cascade)
>
> AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'cascade'

i feel like there is something very simple i'm not doing and would love some help.

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.cascade)

    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

It says i'm supposed to get:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Choice
    - Create model Question
    - Add field question to choice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [**`CASCADE`** - (Ref: Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE) (in **UPPER CASE**)

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

Hence your `models.py` becomes,

```
#models.py
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CASCADE` instead of `cascade`

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```